# how to display two time picker in Linear layout with full view in android

Tags: android

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Class" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tile"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="83dp"
        android:text="Course" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tile"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tile"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="From time" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
            android:text="To time" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TimePicker
                android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleX="0.5"
                android:scaleY="0.5" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TimePicker
                android:id="@+id/timePicker2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleX="0.5"
                android:scaleY="0.5" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/listView1"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Given XML: i am Preparing Layout But in Linearlayout am displaying 2 linear layout and inside that am displaying time Picker but  in that case its display only Hour from time picker and to time picker while i have to display hour ,minute am and pm  all but i am unable to this please help how to fix it

Comment: Better use two "TextView" and on clicking them, start "Time Picker" dialog.

Comment: why cant we set time picker with full view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v.getId() == R.id.imageView1) {
            Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
            mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker,
                                int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                    selectedHour + ":" + selectedHour, 1000)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    }, hour, minute, true);// Yes 24 hour time
            mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
            mTimePicker.show();

        }
    }
```

Use Like this way it will work fine and it will easy .

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to set it to 12h format

```
timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
timePicker.setIs24HourView(false);
timePicker.setCurrentHour(Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
```